# CSS curser:pointer(or other value) is not working on (my) Chrome now

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, cursor, html

Hi I am trying this example on my Chrome 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit Mac).
Seems neither following nor my code works: 
`cursor: pointer`
[Link](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uCwfB) to example which doesn't work for me.

where my codepen example comes from: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/)

Do you have the same problem? A Chrome bug? Thanks!!!

PS: Please don not down grade it if it works for you: works for you doesn't mean works for everyone, it's very basic logic.

Comment: works on my Firefox BTW.

Comment: Works on my Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m in Windows 7.

Comment: As I mentioned, I used Mac (El Capitan)

Comment: Chrome flags reset tried. doesn't help; also tried to use other Chrome account, doesn't help neither.

Comment: it recovered by itself now. No restart, no nothing. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm viewing this in Chrome 46 on a 64-bit Mac (El Capitan) and I'm not seeing any issues.

Try going to chrome://flags to see if this is a flag-enabled feature.

If it is not a feature that was specifically enabled, try disabling all of the flags:

click on <kbd>reset all to default</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am using Mac OS El Capitan.

Comment: I am also viewing this in El Capitan -- no issues.

Comment: Sorry @paceaux I tried to reset but still doesn't help.

Comment: @paceaux Just an update: it recovered by itself now. No restart, no nothing. Just came back. Thanks for your time so far!

Answer (score 0):

Works in my latest updated Chrome browser on a 64 bit-PC-Windows 7 Pro.

Yet your class name is spelled wrong for: .deafult